# IF ISSET not working?

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

IN DB

```
row1 (type column=apple), (stage column=1)
row2 (type column=orange), (stage column=NULL)
```

IN PHP

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from fruits");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $i=0;
    $storeMyData = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if(isset($row['type'])){
            $type = "-" . $row['type'];
        } else {
            $type = NULL;
        }

        if(isset($row['stage'])){
            $stage = "STAGE " . $row['stage'];
        } else {
            $stage = NULL;
        }
        $fruit = implode (", ", array_filter(array($type, $stage)));

    // This will show 2 rows of data
    $storeMyData[] = $fruit;  

    // store current data in array
    $i++;
    }

    /* this will echo your storedData of loop */
    foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)

    /* or join the data using string concatenation */
    $allFinalData2 = "";

    /* this will echo your storedData of loop */
    foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)
    {
        $allFinalData2 = $allFinalData2.$prevData ;  // keep on concatenating
    }

    echo $allFinalData2;
```

The final output shows as "Apple, Stage 1" "Orange, Stage".

How can I show it "Apple, Stage 1" "Orange" without the word Stage if stage is NULL for 
row2 (orange) in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
while($i < $num)
```

to this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

also, there is no need to call mysql_query inside your loop, use this to prevent confusion.

```
$type = "-" . $row['type'];
$stage = "STAGE " . $row['stage'];
```

Comment: i have set my $row to mysql_fetch_array($query); already, but still not working :(

Comment: The variable passed to the mysql_fetch_array must match the rest of your code. At the top you have mysql_num_rows($query), so you should pass the $query variable to your mysql_fetch_array.
Post an updated code listing so we can double check

Comment: the 2nd row of query only shows up with no stage, which is good. However I need to show both rows